# problem in showing tooltip in MS Chart with DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds in Xaxis

Tags: c#

I have a vertical cursor hair in my MS Chart.
In chart I am plotting 10 points. In X axis the interval is 1 second.
When moving cursor hair if it overlaps the datapoint, I have to display tooltip. I am using marker of type circle to represent datapoint.

```
chart.Series[s].BorderWidth = 3;
chart.Series[s].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
chart.Series[s].MarkerSize = 10;
```

I am using below code.

```
void chart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            chart.ChartAreas["history"].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, false);

            try
            {
                if (tt == null) tt = new ChartToolTip();
                tt.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 10.0f);

                // Get the corresponding value of X by mouse position
                double xValue = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
                DataPointCollection p = chart.Series[0].Points;
                int y1 = 0;
                string sp="";
                foreach (DataPoint item in p)
                {

                    if ((xValue < item.XValue) && ((item.XValue - xValue) <= 0.0000009) || (xValue > item.XValue) && ((xValue - item.XValue) <= 0.0000009))
                    {
                        sp = DateTime.FromOADate(item.XValue).ToString();
                        y1 = (int)item.YValues[0];
                        break;
                    }
                }


                DataPointCollection p1 = chart.Series[1].Points;
                int y2 = 0;
                foreach (DataPoint item in p1)
                {
                    if ((xValue < item.XValue) && ((item.XValue - xValue) <= 0.0000009) || (xValue > item.XValue) && ((xValue - item.XValue) <= 0.0000009))
                    {
                        sp = DateTime.FromOADate(item.XValue).ToString();
                        y2 = (int)item.YValues[0];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                string ss = y1.ToString();
                string ss1 = y2.ToString();
                if (y1 == 0 && y2 == 0)
                {
                    tt.Hide(chart);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(xValue);
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(s);
                    if (e.Location != tl)
                    {
                        tt.ToolTipText = sp + "\nLine 1=" + ss + "\nLine 2=" + ss1;
                        tt.Show(tt.ToolTipText, chart, (int)e.Location.X, (int)e.Location.Y);
                    }
                }
                tl = e.Location;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

I could not place the cursor to exactly match  chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X); to datapoint values.
So I put below condition. If I put some condition like, if the difference between datapoint x value and pixelposition x value is less than or equal to 0.0000009 the tooltip is getting diaplyed

**I dont know how to check this difference. I randomly put 0.0000009 but how to calculate this correctly.what is the double value for 1 second?
If I subtract the double value for 2 datetime with 1 second difference(for e.g 05/16/2019,15:08:02,423,613 and 05/16/2019,15:08:03), I am getting the difference 0.00001157407.**

```
foreach (DataPoint item in p)
                {

                    if ((xValue < item.XValue) && ((item.XValue - xValue) <= 0.0000009) || (xValue > item.XValue) && ((xValue - item.XValue) <= 0.0000009))
                    {
                        sp = DateTime.FromOADate(item.XValue).ToString();
                        y1 = (int)item.YValues[0];
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: None of this should be necessary.  When you are over a DataPoint a ToolTip should come up by itself. If you need to code it a HitTest should help to determine over which point you are. Double and float will always show some rounding errors, but as the value of 1 sec = 1,15740767796524E-05 (did you see my previous answer)?? Did it help???)  a much larger epsilon should work.

Comment: @I need to handle the scenario of,  if cursor is on any point of vertical cursor hair line and if vertical cursor hair line overlaps datapoint, I have to show tooltip.